# illegal external reference in amp-restricted function

Tags: c++, c++-amp

If I'm trying to use C++ amp and there are static arrays of constant data that the AMP restricted functions need to access, how can I easily do that (preferrably without mangling the code too much?)

So I have an array:

```
static unsigned char perm[512] = {151,160,137,91,90,15,...};
```

And an amp restricted body that uses that array..

```
float Perlin::noise(float x) restrict(amp)
{
  ...
  n0 = t0 * t0 * grad(perm[i0 & 0xff], x0);
  // causes "illegal external reference in amp-restricted function"
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh388953.aspx - directly states that global variables are not allowed in restricted functions.

Comment: This is so lame.  So it means I'd have to COPY the entire array into _each function_, and then create an `array_view` internal to that function?

Comment: Does "no global variables" imply no member fields for array_view either? Looks like the guidance is to use tile_static: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh388954.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `perm[]` as a static array within your Perlin class and then add an `array_view<const unsigned int, 1>` as a member variable to the class and initialize it in the class constructor. You can then capture `[this]` in your `restrict(amp)` lambda and access the contents of your `perm[]` within each function.

`tile_static` is used to tell the compiler which type of memory to store data in. `tile_static` memory is a limited amount of much faster memory local to each tile. If your C++ AMP lambda reads each value of the perm `array_view` many times then you may see performance improvements by placing the data into `tile_static` memory.